# Force a group in ListCollectionView to be first

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a ListCollectionView as a datacontext to a tab control. I have added a GroupDescription to it based on an enum and I want a particular group to appear as the first tab in the tab control however now it is always being put on the bottom.

```
Profiles = new ListCollectionView(_profiles);
        Profiles.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ProfileType"));
        Profiles.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ProfileName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

_profiles is an ObservableCollection of my profile ViewModels.

My Enum looks like:

```
public enum ProfileTypeEnum
    {
        CurrentSettings,
        CustomSettings,
        DefaultSettings
    }
```

So how can I force the CurrentSettings group to always be first?

Comment: Have you tried change Ascending to Descending?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and it only changes how they are sorted in their groups. Like my Current settings group was just reordered in a descending sort, but the groups stayed in the same position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use an auxiliary property:

```
public class Item
{
    public ProfileTypeEnum ProfileType { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public int ProfileTypeValue { get { return (int)ProfileType; } }
}
```

give values to the enumeration:

```
public enum ProfileTypeEnum
{
    CurrentSettings=0,
    CustomSettings=1,
    DefaultSettings=2
}
```

and add a sort description:

```
Profiles.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ProfileTypeValue", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
Profiles.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ProfileName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

this way you can use enumeration's values to alter the order and force one on top.

Comment: You my friend are a genius it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Really helpful solution. I needed this exactly.